# Convert javascript array into a php unserializable string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to convert a javascript array into a string readable by php "unserialize".

In my javascript, I have:

```
var params = {};
params['showTitle'] = 0;
params['class'] = '';
params['ajax'] = 0;
params['ajaxDom'] = '';
params['what'] = 'defi';
params['color'] = 'dark';
```

The output I ***really need*** to get is this :

```
a:6:{s:9:"showTitle";i:0;s:5:"class";s:0:"";s:4:"ajax";i:0;s:7:"ajaxDom";s:0:"";s:4:"what";s:4:"defi";s:5:"color";s:4:"dark";}
```

Why do I ***need*** this? because the output is red on the server side (with php function unserialize) and I cannot change this (it's part of a framework).

My question is : how to convert the javascript array? I've tried (but didn't work):

```
params = JSON.stringify(params);
params = $.param(params);
```

It should be easy but I'm stuck... Thank you !

Comment: Can't you put in another PHP script in between? Seems rather complicated to simulate PHP's `serialize()`, when there is JSON ...

Comment: FYI: Letting `unserialize` loose on parameters coming from the outside is not recommended – it can be a security risk, because it can under certain conditions be used to initiate objects from classes in the script. A framework should not be doing this in the first place.

Comment: Sirko: I might, I need to try...
CBroe: it's Base64 encode as well! I hope it make things safer ?!?!

Comment: @Siouw Base64 encoding has nothing to do with security!

Comment: Sirko: oops... getting tired (it's kinda late here...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function/answer assumes a lot: mainly that the only two types of data in your JavaScript "array" will be integers and strings, none the less it produces the type of output you demonstrated that the PHP unserialize function requires.

```
var params = {};
params['showTitle'] = 0;
params['class'] = '';
params['ajax'] = 0;
params['ajaxDom'] = '';
params['what'] = 'defi';
params['color'] = 'dark';

function jsArrToPhpSerializedString( arrObj ) {
  var str_parts = ['', '', '}'],
      arrLen = 0,
      ret = '';

  for (var prop in arrObj) {
    var val = arrObj[prop];
    arrLen += 1;
    str_parts[1] += 's:' + prop.length + ':"' + prop + '";';
    if (typeof val == 'number') {
      str_parts[1] += 'i:' + val + ';';
    } else if (typeof arrObj[prop] == 'string') {
      val = (!val) ? '""' : '"' + val + '"';
      str_parts[1] += 's:' + arrObj[prop].length + ':' + val + ';';
    }
  }

  str_parts[0] = 'a:' + arrLen + ':{';
  ret = str_parts.join('');
  return ret;
}

console.log( jsArrToPhpSerializedString(params) );
// "a:6:{s:9:"showTitle";i:0;s:5:"class";s:0:"";s:4:"ajax";i:0;s:7:"ajaxDom";s:0:"";s:4:"what";s:4:"defi";s:5:"color";s:4:"dark";}"
```

Comment: It's exactly, absolutely, perfectly what I needed... works like a charm ! Thank youuuuuuuuu

Comment: No problem. Just beware of the type pitfalls I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Please see if u can make use of this

http://phpjs.org/functions/serialize/

Comment: I can't get it works :( But I think I might try jstice4all's solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just send that js array to the server as JSON, then parse it with [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and serialize it with [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) function. Then you can unserialize it.

Comment: But I can't change the php part :(

Comment: But can you insert a intermediate php part into the the flow? Seems like you can, the javascript is sending it off somewhere, it could send it off to the intermediate php script as suggested before that intermediate php script sends it to the place javascript was sending.

Comment: Ok. Then Sunand's answer is more suitable in your case.

Comment: ssnobody: Oh right :) I really need some sleep... sorry! jstice4all: I'll try that first thing tomorrow morning! thx